# How to set different repeat and repeat_delay values in FuncAnimation in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

How can I set different "repeat" and/or "repeat_delay" values in FuncAnimation, considering that I need to save it as a one GIF image?
Or in other words, is it possible to customize FuncAnimation for different entities?

For example I want to set repeat=False only for circles.
Is it possible at all?
Thank you!

```
anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=frames, interval=600, repeat=True, repeat_delay=0)
```

Here is a minimum reproducible example of the code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

import matplotlib.patches as patches

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_ylim(-20, 20)
ax.set_xlim(-20, 20)

circle_size = 400

point_anim1 = ax.scatter(10, 10, s=circle_size, c='red')
point_anim2 = ax.scatter(-10, -4, s=circle_size, c='blue')

arrow = patches.Arrow(2, 2, 2, 2)
ax.add_patch(arrow)
frames = 6

def animate(i):
    global point_anim1, point_anim2
    point_anim1.remove()
    point_anim2.remove()
    if i % 2:
        point_anim1 = ax.scatter(10, 10, s=circle_size * i, c='red')
        point_anim2 = ax.scatter(-10, -4, s=circle_size * i, c='blue')
        arrow.set_visible(False)
    else:
        point_anim1 = ax.scatter(10, 10, s=circle_size, c='red')
        point_anim2 = ax.scatter(-10, -4, s=circle_size, c='blue')
        arrow.set_visible(True)
    return arrow, point_anim1, point_anim2,


anim = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=frames, interval=600, repeat=True, repeat_delay=0)
plt.show()
plt.close()

anim.save('test.gif', writer='pillow')
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: What's your ultimate goal? What do you want the animation to do?

Comment: @jared my goal is to set different values (f.e. "repeat" parameter) for different plots in FuncAnimation in matplotlib.